# Does Phonegap/Titanium allow for self updates

Tags: html, web-applications, mobile-phones, cordova, titanium

Just wanting to get a bit more of an idea about how Phonegap/Titanium packages its assets (i.e. HTML, JS, CSS, etc). Does it compile these assets as part of the package/app or does it download these assets from the server as required. In other words, is it navigating between "pages" on the mobile device or can it navigate between pages hosted on the server.

If its the former, can you download updated assets from the server or does it require the whole application to updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the content as you navigate through pages using AJAX.

[This is an example](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ch03.html#ch03_id35817028)